# Simple Form Collection expects Array (got String) for Params but I am expecting a String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-7

In my Rails application I have a pronouns input field for the  method. I want the user to select from an array of strings `['he/him', 'she/her', 'they/them', 'other']`.

`**schema.rb (users table)** t.string "pronouns"`

I have tried so many different things - one array with 4 strings, an array with 4 arrays and only one string because my label and value are the same, and the solution you can see below.

```
**edit.html.erb**

<%= f.input :pronouns,
      collection: [['he/him', 'he/him'] , ['she/her', 'she/her'], ['they/them', 'they/them'], ['other', 'other']],
      label_method: :first,
      value_method: :second,
      required: true,
      autofocus: true %>
```

**error message when I submit the form**

`ActionController::BadRequest Invalid request parameters: expected Array (got String) for param pronouns'`

But by now, I don't think my form is the issue. I don't refer to the pronouns anywhere besides in my schema file though. I don't know why it is expecting an array. And if the collection option itself expects an array, why my current solution doesn't work.

Comment: Note that in HTML, we use a `<select>` element when there is a list to choose from. `<input>` allows free-form input and isn't limited to a list. You should find the equivalent in ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [select form_helper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) ex:

```
<%= f.select :pronouns, ['he/him', 'she/her', 'they/them', 'they/them', 'other'], required: true, autofocus: true %>
```